# How to know the total memory allocated by a process since its creation

Tags: c#, .net, memory, memory-management, clr

We are trying to setup a regression test environment on which our app would be installed, replayed some traffic and then compared with a "prod grade" version of the same app. After the replay, we would compare key metrics from both version, both business and technical.

One of the metrics is how much memory has been allocated by the process since its creation, to make sure the current version is not allocating significantly more than the "prod grade" version. But I cannot find in the PerformanceCounters or in the System.Diagnostics any metrics that would give us this information.

I understand that the GC frees memory all the time, but what I want to count is how much memory has been allocated a bit like `System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().TotalProcessorTime` does for the CPU consumed (At least I think it does).

Edit: To say it differently, what I want to measure is the total memory in the gen0-1-2 PLUS all the memory that has been freed by the numerous GCs that have run in my process.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not interested by a snapshot of the memory used or available, but by the cumulative memory allocated since the birth of the process. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For .Net Framework [`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.MonitoringTotalAllocatedMemorySize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.monitoringtotalallocatedmemorysize?view=netframework-4.8.1) gives this.

For .Net Core there is also [`System.GC.GetTotalAllocatedBytes()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.gettotalallocatedbytes?view=net-8.0).

I'm not sure what the difference is, in my experimenting `System.GC.GetTotalAllocatedBytes(true)` gave a very accurate count seeing even a single additional object allocation.  `System.GC.GetTotalAllocatedBytes(false)`  and `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.MonitoringTotalAllocatedMemorySize` seem to give the same value and only update after several allocations.

Answer (score -2):

You can add the performance counter through the run dialog, just type in perfmon . then just select the counter then reference it with Diagnostics. here is a tutorial i have done on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=niKP91D50Ko

also its basics are

```
using system.Diagnostics;

PerformanceCounter perfCPUCounter  = new PerformanceCounter(" "," "," ");
```

in the quotations you want to put the `Object`, `Counter`, and `Instance` in the quotations. If there are three `---` then it does not take anything an leave it omitted.

Comment: It looks like your link points to monitoring CPU, not memory. Also, which performance counter records the cumulative memory allocated since the birth of the process?

Comment: there are literally hundreds of counters. Think out side the box. The system keeps up with the numbers by using counters `perfmon` and in the perfmon you go to the memory section. in my tutorial i show to get the memory being used by the programs being run, however what your looking for is in the memory section. My tutorial shows you how to get there.. i will look it up real quick and tell you

Comment: i did three performance counters just give the idea what you could do. As i stated there are hundreds of counters. But if you want how much memory is being used on say on Chrome then you would use `AvailableMBytes` and you create a label to give you the stats, if you want the cached then you use `Cache Bytes` what exactly are trying to measure the total memory used by the system r an application?

Comment: My question wasn't clear. I am not trying to measure the memory allocated at a certain point in time, but the total memory that has been allocated since the birth of the process, including the memory that has been freed by the numerous GCs that have run. I just updated the question to be more clear.

Comment: Errr... I'm not sure I'm familiar with the terminology `memory process life`

Comment: lets say memory process is 1456 of 1556 at the current time its using 100 MB, now you want memory process of when it started to end 187445664MB lets say over a one year period. you can get the current memory count but if you want all the memory processes added up to give a total, then its almost to near impossible because the memory is always over writing and deleting memory usage. So to get the total usage of the process from a year would be impossible since it deletes cached memory to make space for new memory. If you understand what i am saying

Comment: take a cup and fill it with water, you can see that cup has collected x amount of water over time. When that cup over flows then there is no way of knowing how much total water has ran into the cup.

Comment: Hmmm. I feel a bit lost. A GC running can easily add in some int64 the amount of memory it freed over time. That's all the memory that had been allocated. It doesn't look hard at all. Add that to the current footprint and you have what I want. To go back to the water analogy, it NEVER overflows. Sometimes the GC kicks in and scoop a little bit of water out of your cup. It feels easy to record...

Comment: waht about the water that is scooped out? Where does it go? It does not get scooped out of memory to be placed back in memory. That defeats the point of how memory works. The only way to get an estimate is the cached file, even then the cached file gets deleted when you do a ystem clean such as CCleaner. SO if you never clean the System cache out then its plausible. However to much cache and your ram will overload and fail.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122257/discussion-between-pieroxy-and-campnerd).